# Slickgrid - How to add css at grid creation time?

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

I'm using SlickGrid v2.1 and I would like to add a css class to my grid's row, during it's **creation time**, based on a data source value. For example, given the code below:

```
var data = [];

var columns = [
    {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title", width: 120},
    {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"}
]

... [data initialization] ...

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

I want to add a css class, "test", to a row if it's duration cell value is equal to 99. How can one do this? I've tried to do this by adding custom formatter to the duration column but I cant access the grid's canvas methods.

I've searched the web regarding this matter but didnt find any help. Any help would be much appreciated!

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up getting the correct way to do this. One has got to implement getItemMetadata as explained here: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Providing-data-to-the-grid.

The code:

```
       function getItemMetadata(row){
            if(data[row].duration === 99){
                return { 'cssClasses': 'test' }
            }
        }
```

Best regards

Comment: +1 - Nice! Feel free to mark this as the answer to the question (just click on the checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

In your format function you could grab the row by referencing the DOM component directly.

```
function YourFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {

    //JavaScript
    document.getElementsByClassName('ui-widget-content slick-row')[row].className += ' test';

    //jQuery
    //$('.ui-widget-content.slick-row').eq(row).addClass('test');

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brandon, but your solution only adds the class after the creation of the grid.. I also posted the same question on Slickgrid's google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/slickgrid/Tt9qpREpGTQ) and there I got the trick. One just got to implement getItemMetaData function, as explained here: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Providing-data-to-the-grid